# Python - Import works in base, but not conda virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

So I'm trying to use the libary [paretochart](https://github.com/tisimst/paretochart), and after some install trouble (installed & uninstalled with `pip`) I took the simplest recommended route on the `READ.me` and just downloaded the main `paretochart.py` file.

I can then do:

```
import paretochart 
from paretochart import pareto
```

However, executing either of the above with my virtual environment results in python crashing:

[image]

[image]

What are the reasons an import statement can  behave differently between a `conda` environment and the base?

Comment: wait, why are you mixing `conda` and `virtualenv`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry for the confusion, I mistyped. I'm just using [conda environments](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)

Comment: OK, I think you are going to have to provide more details if you want help. What, *exactly* are you doing? What *exactly* do you mean by "python crashing"? etc, etc

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks for the feedback, I added a picture. But not sure what else details I can give. On the base python environment, `import paretochart` works and causes no errors. When I do `import paretochart` in my conda environment, python quite literally just crashes. I have no clue the reasons this could be case, so was looking for help on what I could do to investigate the source of this error

Comment: right, again, what exactly are the commands you are running. What exactly are you doing? What environment are you wrooking in, IDE, terminal, etc

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Just running this on `anaconda prompt`, as updated in the question

Comment: 1) Please don't post terminal input/output in images, see here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481 2) The command should be `conda activate envname` with recent versions of conda 3) Did you install this package in your second environment?

Comment: Looking at [the source](https://github.com/tisimst/paretochart/blob/master/paretochart/paretochart.py), `paretochart` imports `matplotlib.pyplot`. Can you use `matplotlib.pyplot` in your conda env without seeing this crash? Also the installation instructions tell you to run `2to3` on it before using it with Python 3.x, have you done this?